# Zig error: Array access of non-array type

Tags: arrays, zig

I need some help on creating an array as a struct field in Zig.

```
const VarStr = struct {
    buffer: [1000]u8,
    len: u8,
    pub fn init(str: []const u8) VarStr {
        var filled: u8 = 0;
        for (str) |char, ind| {
            .buffer[ind] = char;
            filled = ind + 1;
        }
        while (filled < 999) {
            .buffer[filled] = null;
        }
    }
};
```

When i compile, it gives me the following error

```
error: array access of non-array type '@Type(.EnumLiteral)'
            .buffer[ind] = char;
                   ^
```

Where did I go wrong? please help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.buffer` is not valid zig syntax*. Zig does not have any kind of implicit `this` object in structs, so you have to make one yourself.

```
const VarStr = struct {
    buffer: [1000]u8,
    len: u8,
    pub fn init(str: []const u8) VarStr {
        var result: VarStr = .{
            .buffer = undefined,
            .len = @intCast(u8, str.len),
        };
        var filled: u8 = 0;
        for (str) |char, ind| {
            result.buffer[ind] = char;
            filled = ind + 1;
        }
        while (filled < 999) {
            result.buffer[filled] = null;
        }
    }
};
```

This code will now compile, but it's going to go into an infinite loop because `filled` in the while never changes. If you're trying to copy the first 999 bytes into `buffer` and fill the rest with zeroes, you might consider:

```
var result: VarStr = .{
    .buffer = [_]u8{0} ** 1000, // zero-initialize buffer
    .len = std.math.min(str.len, @as(u8, 999)),
};
std.mem.copy(u8, &result.buffer, str[0..std.math.min(str.len, 999)]);
```

*: `.buffer` is syntax for a zig enum literal. Enum literals are used as a shorthand for using enum fields. `.buffer[index]` is meaningless because you cannot index an enum literal, which is what the error means by `array access of non-array type '@Type(.EnumLiteral)'`